# are all the terms of this chaotic map 0s?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, computer-science, cryptography, chaos-theory

I'm trying to implement the algorithm proposed on this paper: [A Simple Method for Image Encryption Using
Chaotic Logistic Map](https://www.jcscm.net/fp/32.pdf)
but i cannot figure out the equation (7), i'm pretty sure that $X_0=0$, because is the sum of integer products (5) and (6). So, if that is the case, it means: the terms  $X_1,X_2, X_3, X_4..$ of (1) are also 0, which make no sense to me. Is not supposed that the terms of the map (1) will be pseudo-random numbers?
I searched on other journals to check if it was a typo error, but is not the case. So the only thing that come to my mind is that i don't undertand the notation used in this paper. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the square brackets in $(5)$ and $(6)$ indicate division by $2^{40}$; compare $(6)$ and $(7)$ in [this PDF](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.88.5203&rep=rep1&type=pdf). That reduces $X_{01}$ and $X_{02}$ to the range $(0,1)$, so that $(8)$ puts $X_0\in(0,1)$, where it should be.

Comment: it could be, but i was unable to find any resource that confirm it.  I was thinking maybe is not division, maybe is bit shift operation.

Comment: @Brocolio: Not a bit shift: it’s just putting the binary point at the front of the string. And realistically it can’t be anything else, especially with the confirmation from the paper by Pareek et al.

Comment: Oh, i get your point about moving the floating point, my understanding is, the square bracket mean division by $2^n$ where n is the number of terms right? If that is the case, what about (7) in the paper that you mention?

Comment: @Brocolio: I’m not sure what’s going on in $(7)$. Each $k_i$ is a $4$-bit string, so it has $16$ possible values, and the sum is over $6$ of them, and I don’t think that it’s an accident that the denominator $96$ is $6\cdot 16$. My best guess is that $(k_i)_{10}$ is the base ten interpretation of the string $k_i$, in which case the sum is between $0$ and $90$, inclusive, and dividing by $96$ ensures that it’s between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: that make sense to me, i think i can move on using those insights, thanks for your answers!

Comment: @Brocolio: You’re welcome!